# Place a UIView on top of a UINavigationcontroller in landscape mode

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, overlay

what would be the best way to show a UIView on top of a UINavigationController when in landscape mode?
Trying

[self.navigationController.view addSubView: myView]

places myView under the Navigationbar.

[self.window addSubView: myView]

will show myView in portrait orientation (i.e. 90 degrees rotated to the left or right). I could rotate, but I hope there is a better solution.

Is there any way to cover the entire NavigationController with a UIView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add the view to UIWindow and rotate it depending on the current orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just hide the navigation bar of the Navigation Controller ?
Like this : `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES`

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I would like to add a view on top of the screen, even a UINavigationcontroller. This is possible by adding the view to the window, but the window is always in portrait mode and hence the view, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following.
You only want the view to be there in landscape mode. So, you should do the following pice of code in

didRotateToInterfaceOrientation: method,  hide the view when it rotates to potrait mode and show it when it rotates in landscape mode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I don't want landscape exclusively- I would like to add a view on top of a screen with a UINavigationController, no matter what the current orientation is.